# Help on the evaluation of a sum

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I'm reading a paper and came across a specific sum that I can't seem to wrap my head around,

\begin{align}
\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < i_3 < \dots < i_{p-1} < i_p} x^{i_1 + i_2 + \dots + i_p} = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < i_3 < \dots < i_{p-1}}  x^{i_1 + i_2 + \dots + i_{p-1}} \sum_{i > i_{p-1}}x^i
\end{align}

Could someone please explain what the sum means? $\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < i_3 < \dots < i_{p-1} < i_p}$, I'm quite certain I can figure it out from here.

I know this question is quite trivial, and will understand if it is flagged. Thanks in advance for any help/advice offered.

Answer (score 1):

It just means you are summing over all possible $p$-tuples $(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_p)$ where $1\leq i_1$ and $i_k<i_{k+1}$ for all $1\leq k<p$.

For example, if $p=3$, then the summands corresponding to all $p$-tuples with $i_p\leq 5$ correspond to $$(i_1,i_2,i_3)\in\{(1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,2,5),(1,3,4),(1,3,5),(1,4,5),(2,3,4),(2,3,5),(2,4,5),(3,4,5)\}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it must just be something trivial like that. Thanks so much buddy! And that also explains the bit about splitting the sum into the two parts :)